# Not Visible Individually Still Showing In Search Results

Tags: magento-1.9

When we set products visibility to either 'Catalog' or 'Not Visible Individually' they still show up in the search results.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: This is most likely a cache issue. Did you flush the cache correctly?

Comment: ^^ Also try reindexing

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

showing simple products which belongs to configurable products and already set to '**Not Visible Individually**'.  You can add these products to cart and checkout but click in will lead to 404 page.

My case is that, these products are imported by nonstandard `import tool/script`, products missing some required fields.

What I did to make them disappear is to save them again(try one product first). Filter all "**enable**" products, than change their status to "**enable**" and submit(this will save these product again). do the same to disabled product.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:-

1) Either, change the Visibility of the product to Nowhere for each store you have.

– While editing product, in the top left corner, you will see ‘Choose Store View’
– Choose the store where you want the product visibility to Nowhere
– Now, edit the visibility to Nowhere and Save the product

2) The second solution is to directly change the Visibility attribute Scope.

– Go to `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes`
– Edit Visibility attribute
– Change the Scope to ‘Global’

I prefer the first solution. But, it might depend upon your need and ease.